# How do I implement a UITextfield that increases in height as I type?

Tags: iphone

A very simple problem but I have found no solution. How do I implement a UITextfield that increases in height as I type? This would be the type of control you see in iPhone's native SMS app send bar. When you press new line, the control increases in height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `UITextViewDelegate` implementation of `textViewDidChange:` you need to calculate the size of the text for the specific width and adjust accordingly.

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSString *text = [textView text];
    NSFont *font = [textView font];
    CGFloat width = [textView frame].size.width;

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    /* Adjust text view width with "size.height" */
}
```

Comment: Does this work with a UITextField as the question asks?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `UITextView` instead. In either case you can use the `TextDidChange` notification (called editing changed in IB) to check the size of your text and update the height accordingly.